# Store Values through Array or Use Function? (to optimize)

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, function, optimization

In Python, I have a variable `x` (dependant on another vairable `i`) that takes following values :

```
x = 0.5 for i=11 or i=111 
x = 1   for 12<=i<=100 or 112<=i<=200
x = 0   for the rest of the values of i (i takes integer values from 1 to 300)
```

I wish to use value of `x` many times inside a loop (where `i` is NOT the iterator). Which would be the better (computation time saving) way to store values of `x`: Array or function?

I can store it as array of length of 300 and assign above values. Or I can have function `get_x` that takes value of `i` as input and gives above values according to `if` condition.

I want to optimize my code for time. Which way would be better? (I am trying to implement this in Python and MATLAB as well.)

Comment: Have you tried profiling it?

Comment: @TonyTheLion No, I haven't. I was hoping there would be a general practice that I am not aware of.

Comment: You cannot *store* things through a function. That being said: MATLAB is optimised to use matrices, and since an array is simply a one dimensional matrix the array will be the  better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is entirely dependent on your application, and anyway I would tend towards the philosophy of avoiding premature optimization. Probably just implement it in whichever way looks cleanest or makes the most sense to you, and if it ends up being too slow try something different.

But if you really do insist upon seeing real results, let's take a look. Here's the code I used to run this:

```
import time
import random

def get_x(i):
    if i == 11 or i == 111:
        return 0.5
    if (12 <= i and i <= 100) or (112 <= i and i <= 200):
        return 1
    return 0

x_array = [get_x(i) for i in range(300)]
i_array = [i % 300 for i in range(1000000)]
print "Sequential access"
start = time.time()
for i in i_array:
    x = get_x(i)
end = time.time()
print "get_x method:", end-start

start = time.time()
for i in i_array:
    x = x_array[i]
end = time.time()
print "Array method:", end-start
print

random.seed(123)
i_array = [random.randint(0,299) for i in range(1000000)]
print "Random access"
start = time.time()
for i in i_array:
    x = get_x(i)
end = time.time()
print "get_x method:", end-start

start = time.time()
for i in i_array:
    x = x_array[i]
end = time.time()
print "Array method:", end-start
```

Here's what it prints out:

```
Sequential access
get_x method: 0.264999866486
Array method: 0.108999967575

Random access
get_x method: 0.263000011444
Array method: 0.108999967575
```

Overall neither method is very slow, this is for 10^6 accesses and they both easily complete within a quarter of a second. The get_x method does appear to be about twice as slow as the array method. However, this will not be the slow part of your loop logic! Anything else you put in that loop will certainly be the main cause of your program's execution time. You should definitely choose the method makes your code easier to maintain, which is probably the `get_x` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the function, maybe it could be a little slower since the function creates a new scope in the stack of memory but it will be more readable, and as the Python's Zen says: "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: I completely agree with this.

Answer (score 1):

Precomputing x and then doing lookup will be faster for each lookup but will pay for itself only if enough lookups are done to outweigh the cost of precomputing all the values each time the program is run. The break-even point can be computed based on benchmarks, but perhaps not worth the effort. Another strategy is to not do precomputation but for every computation memoize or cache its results. Some caching strategies such as reddis and memcache allow persistance between program runs.

Based on testing with timeit, list access is between 3.5-7.3 times faster than computation depending on the value of i. Below are some test results.

```
def f(i):
    if i == 11 or i == 111:
        return .5
    else:
        if i >= 12 and i <= 100 or i >= 112 and i <= 200:
            return 1
    return 0

timeit f(11)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 139 ns per loop

timeit f(24)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 215 ns per loop

timeit f(150)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 249 ns per loop

timeit f(105)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 267 ns per loop

timeit f(237)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 289 ns per loop

x = range(300)

timeit x[150]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.5 ns per loop

timeit x[1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ns per loop

timeit x[299]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ns per loop
```